# Is "in her pride she sat" grammatical and idiomatic?

Tags: meaning, idioms, idiomatic-language

Is "in her pride she sat" grammatical and idiomatic?

> In her pride, she sat quietly and observed the loudmouths around her.
>
> She stood there quietly in her pride.
>
> She isolated herself from the others in her pride.

I am not sure if it's idiomatic, because I rarely ever encountered similar sentences. I think it's grammatical, but I am not sure if it's idiomatic.

Saw some examples on the Internet with similar wording:

> In his pride he performed many a wonder until the high King of Kings,
>   who sees and knows all things, took vengeance on his pride (2809).

Comment: Is she a [lion](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-a-lion-pride-130300)? Perhaps "She stood there quietly and proudly."

Comment: So is "in her pride" unidiomatic? Why?

Comment: You are describing two qualities of the subject, one as an adverb and one as a noun. As my link suggests, the sentences make her seem like she is with her lion family, and they are not idiomatic.

Comment: Is it idiomatic if I say: In her pride, she stood there quietly?

Comment: Sounds 'poetic'...!

Comment: The first example sentence is perfect. The other two are ambiguous: they could mean she stood/isolated herself proudly, or it could mean she was a lion. Even if the rest of the context makes it clear she's not a lion, it would sound weird. Both are totally clear if you begin with "In her pride, ..."

Comment: If she's a lioness, it's definitely grammatical and idiomatic.

Comment: A fairy tale might say, "In her pride she thought she could command the winds to blow." But there's no pride evident in her sitting or standing quietly, or even in her isolating herself. We might say, "In her haste she forgot the cinema tickets" or "In her fury she ripped to pieces the flowers he had given her."

Answer (score 1):

It seems grammatically correct. However, "in her pride" would not be the way most native speakers would phrase that. I might say something like, "She sat in dignified silence and observed the loudmouths around her". I think "dignity" fits better. "Pride" can have negative connotations. "She was too proud to talk to the other people". In other words, she thought she was better than everyone else.

Answer (score 1):

All three sentences are grammatically correct but none are idiomatic. The first version would be OK in a literary context, but is not suitable for general writing or conversation. The other two would sound unnatural in any context.

The particular example that you quoted is quite literary: "many a wonder" is also a literary turn of phrase.

As others have said, **pride** might not be the right word. I recommend consulting a good dictionary like [this one](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/pride), and check whether any of the meanings match what you want to say.